# How to generate random list and insert into listview

Tags: java, arrays, listview, random

I am trying to put random items from an array and insert them into a listview, at the moment the listview is just coming up blank. Ideally I would like to be able to retrieve what position from the array the list item is if it is clicked on too

```
String[] levelOneListList = new String[] {
            "Daisy", "Rock", "Tree", "Dandelion", "Grass"
    };

Random r=new Random();
    int randomNumber=r.nextInt(levelOneListList.length);

    ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_checked, randomNumber);
```

The listview is now empty on the emulator

Answer (score 0):

Try to take a look at this page. It's a good Tutorial on how to use Listviews with ArrayAdapter.
https://guides.codepath.com/android/Using-an-ArrayAdapter-with-ListView